# Display shadow-box over contained elements

Tags: css

I'd like to display a list of elements inside of a container div. This container div has an inner shadow box. Unfortunately, the shadow box goes underneath the contained elements, as you can see here

[image]

Now obviously, this is both illogical and non-esthetic. I dug around, and someone gave [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459669/box-shadow-not-going-over-background-color-of-contained-element). The problem is, I need to be able to scroll inside of this container, for the contained divs will most likely overflow.

Is there a way to display this shadow over the contained divs ?

Comment: share the code instead of image

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not provided any source code, some better way to achive this is

```css
.parent {
    box-shadow : inset 0 0 5px 0 black;
    height:200px;
    position :relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
    background : rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    height:1000px;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    foo
    <div class="content">bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, actually, I got the exact same code as you, the only difference is I set the opacity to 1. I don't want to see the shadow through the contained div, I'd like to see it onto (mostly because i'd like my contained div to be plain white)